# How to profile my rspec tests to find the biggest memory hogs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, profiling

We use circleci as part of our deployment process.  Circleci runs our 3000 tests and sometimes fails because it hits a 4 GB memory limit.  It looks like some of our tests are creating a lot of objects and using up a ton of memory. I just don't know which ones are.

Is there an easy way for me to profile the memory used for a given test?  If I knew how to do this, I could easily loop through each test and run it and see how much memory it uses.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ruby-prof](https://ruby-prof.github.io/) gem to profile memory usage. But first you might try running RSpec with the [`--profile` flag](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-2/docs/configuration/profile-examples). It will give you the 10 slowest specs which is probably a good place to start looking for specs that are consuming massive amounts of memory.

Comment: The --profile flag will tell you which tests are slow but not necessarily which tests are memory intensive.